# Use For Loop to output name in array?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, random, count

i need your help .So i am studying at codecademy and i have such exercise :

> In our game, we'll make a list of our closest family and friends and have a lottery. 
>   We will "spin the wheel" and randomly select one of our family and friends from the list.
>   Create an array() with the names of your closest family and friends. 
>   The more names in your array, the more fun your game will be!
>
> After you've created your list, sort it and randomly select a name from the list.
>
> When you have your winning name, print it to the screen in caps so everyone knows how awesome the winner is.

So the first way it can be done ,is like this,it is accurate :

```
   <?php
$fam=array();
array_push($fam,"Alla"); 
array_push($fam,"Serega");
array_push($fam,"Anna");
array_push($fam,"Alla");
array_push($fam,"Sonia");
sort($fam);
$num=count($fam);

$rand=rand(0,$num-1);

 print strtoupper($fam[$rand]);    

?>
```

> BUT I WANT TO DO IT THROUGH FOR LOOP ,LIKE THIS :

```
<?php   
     $fam=array();
    array_push($fam,"Alla"); 
    array_push($fam,"Serega");
    array_push($fam,"Anna");
    array_push($fam,"Alla");
    array_push($fam,"Sonia");
    sort($fam);
    $num=count($fam);


    for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){

       $fam[$i]=rand(0,5);
       print strtoupper($fam[$i]);
       break;
        }

    ?>
```

> *The problem that in the for loop it outputs the random number but
>   not random name in the array $fam! How to do this properly using FOR
>   LOOP???!!!*

Comment: What exactly is the for loop supposed to do?

Comment: I'm not sure why you used `break;`. If you want to print one name then no need to use loop.

Comment: Sorry guys,I just misunderstood some simple things,Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting names:

```
$fam[$i]=rand(0,5); // <= HERE YOU SET NEW VALUE FOR i-th ARRAY ELEMENT
print strtoupper($fam[$i]);
```

To accomplish what you want you need to [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) your array:

```
shuffle($fam);
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++){
  print strtoupper($fam[$i]);
}
```